# how to take out flowtype from react Js code?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, flowtype, static-typing

I've integrated flow-bin v0.122.0 and used it in my react+redux project. now i want to run my project thus need react code without flow type. how do i do that ? in the [documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/) related to react part has one piece of advice but I don't understand it and it doesn't work. whenever i add this the flow server stops working and won't restart. what do i do ?

here is my [package.json](https://github.com/arkapratimsarkar/learn-react-redux/blob/map-props/package.json)

Comment: Can you expand a bit more, what exactly doesn't work? Because you've bootstrapped your application with `create-react-app` you shouldn't need any additional config. See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-flow/. If you've setup a project from scratch you'll instead need [@babel/preset-flow](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-flow) but I don't think you have that situation. Maybe some additional info on what breaks and screenshots would go a long way

Comment: @Brianzchen yes you are right. I,m new to flowtype and very confused how to use it in various cases. in this particular case I was getting errors as I assigned": function" as types to some functions.

Comment: You're probably looking for `: Function` as capital `F`. But I'd also recommend not using `Function` type as it's deprecated. Have a read of this https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#toc-function-type